# How to compile and link multiple python modules (or packages) using cython?

Tags: python, compilation, package, cython

I have several python modules (organized into packages), which **depend on each other**. e.g.

- Module1
- Module2: imports Module1
- Module3
- Module4: imports Module3, Module 2, Module 1

Let's assume the relevant interface to develop applications is in Module4 and I want to generate a Module4.so using **cython**.
If I proceed in the naive way, I get an extension Module4.so which I can import **BUT** the extension **relies on the python source code** of Module1, Module2, Module3.

Is there a way to compile so that also Module1,Module2, Module3 are **compiled and linked** to Module4? I would like to **avoid doing everything manually**, e.g. first compile Module1.so then change import declaration in Module2, so as to import Module1.so rather than Module1.py, then compile Module2 into Module2.so and so on....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit. First two options refer to Cython's specific code, what I've missed is that the question is about pure python modules, so option 3 is the solution.

There are a few options:

1.
See this "How To Create A Hierarchy Of Modules In A Package":
https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/PackageHierarchy

2.
I prefer the "include" statement:
http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#the-include-statement
I have many .pyx files and they are all included in main.pyx, it's all in one namespace. The result is one big module: http://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython.pyx

3.
You can compile all your modules at once using setup by adding more than one "Extension":

```
setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("example", sourcefiles), Extension("example2", sourcefiles2), Extension("example3", sourcefiles3)]
)
```

4.
A more efficent compilation - see [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-distutils_preprocessing).

```
setup (
    name = 'MyProject',
    ext_modules = cythonize(["*.pyx"]),
)
```

Comment: thanks, so option 3 would take care to automatically import Module3.so rather than Module3.py (I'am referring to the example above)?

Comment: @Mannaggia, Ahh, now I see that you don't use Cython specific features  ("pyx" files), you only want to compile normal python modules using cython. Yes, a statement "import Module1" works for importing "Module1.py" or "Module1.so" - just don't put both files in the same directory as I don't know which module will be imported then. Nothing changes, .so is treated just like a .py file when importing.

Comment: @Mannaggia, Nothing changes, .so is treated just like a .py file when importing. After you have compiled .py modules to .so everything should work out of the box.

Comment: ok, seems to work, I initially renamed all .py files into .pyx files and compiled everything. However, I had problems importing modules, the problem was that I should keep the _\_\_init\_\_.py file for each package, I did this and then it run smoothly

Comment: By the way, I used approach 1 (which from my understanding is a way to automate 3), because I need to use the original namespace when importing modules. If I would merge all in one namespace then I have to edit lots of source files replacing each _import package1.module1 with _import module1, etc. I also removed the package declaration part (line 52 at code from http://wiki.cython.org/PackageHierarchy) and it works