# Compile a Python application to C

Tags: python, c

I have made an application in Python. It contains several plugins, organized into different subdirectories. I need to compile entirely to C code to improve security of source code. I have dealt with Cython, but cannot find how to compile the entire directory, with all plugin dependencies. I need a way to compile each of the dependencies to C, and that the application runs from C compiled.

http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html

[How to compile and link multiple python modules (or packages) using cython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507101/how-to-compile-and-link-multiple-python-modules-or-packages-using-cython)

Comment: You are aware that in C you compile the application for a particular platform?

Comment: It contains several plugins, then ask each plugin author. if they don't support it, out of the question.

Comment: Why is *"security of source code"* such a big issue? It's not as if compiled C cannot be decompiled - you should focus on *legal*, rather than *technological*, protection here.

Comment: You probably want just to compile python, use `nuitka` then.

Comment: C is easier to disassemble.

Comment: @Scony that doesn't solve the problem for the same reason that compiling to C wouldn't.

Comment: I know C is compiled for a particular platform. I'm working on Linux (Ubuntu).
The idea behind the C compilation is put some barriers to access source code. No let alone written in python.

Answer (score 3):

Python does not compile to native code. Scripts can be "frozen" with a few different tools, which makes them into standalone executables, but it's not actually compiling to C, it's packaging the script (or just its Python byte code representation) with a copy of the interpreter and all of its dependencies; the binary still has all the Python code (or the trivial byte code transform thereof) in it.

Cython lets you compile a syntactic variant of Python into Python C extensions, but they still run on the Python interpreter, and they still expose enough information to reverse the transformation.

Get the proper legal protections in place and freeze your Python executable if you like (freezing is enough to make the source code "non-obvious" even if anyone who went to trivial effort could get it back), but Python does not compile to plain C directly (if it did, I'd expect the CPython reference interpreter to do that more often just to gain performance with the built-in modules, yet they only write C accelerators by hand).

Comment: The idea behind the C compilation is put some barriers to access source code. No let alone written in python.

Comment: @Reki: I don't understand what you mean by "No let alone written in python."

Comment: Do not leave the project files in .py